$a_n$ increasing, $\sum\frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges $\implies\exists\ n_1<n_2<n_3,$ such that $\vert (a_{n_3}-a_{n_2})-(a_{n_2}-a_{n_1})\vert<\varepsilon$
I want to know if the following proposition is true or false, or if it is more-or-less equivalent to Erdos conjecture.

Proposition: For any fixed $\varepsilon>0$ and any increasing real sequence
$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum
 \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges, then $\ \exists\ n_1<n_2<n_3,$ such that $\vert (a_{n_3} -a_{n_2}) - (a_{n_2}-a_{n_1})\vert <
 \varepsilon. $


Possibly related: Here, it says that, "The weaker claim that A must contain infinitely many arithmetic progressions of length 3 is a consequence of an improved bound in Roth's theorem."
Also possibly related: Has this weak version of Erdős Conjecture on arithmetic progressions been proven, or is it still an open problem?
Is it the case that if the proposition were true, then Erdos conjecture would be true?

Are you sure that you don't want absolute values there?

I take it that each $a_n$ is a positive integer?

@ThomasAndrews I think my edit should solve that issue.

@LeeMosher No: $a_n$ are real numbers, not necessarily integers.

@LeeMosher that would be odd, because it would just mean they are equal for some $n_1,n_2,n_3,$

Okay, but then the Erdos conjecture (your first link) and your second link are both about sequences where each $a_n$ is a positive integer. Why would one expect those other conjectures to be associated with your statement?

@LeeMosher Because for example, if there were a sequence for which the proposition failed for some $\varepsilon,$ then multiplying all members of the sequence by $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ (and then flooring or ceiling some or all those numbers) might get you close to an integer sequence relevant to the links or something related to Erdos conjecture.

@AdamRubinson: After posting an answer I realize that you never state that $\epsilon $ is positive. Is that an omission or is $\epsilon \le 0$  allowed?

@MartinR  No I meant $\varepsilon>0,$ and have now amended this in the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

As it stands now, do you need to say "pairwise distinct" in the title? [I would think that is implied by the inequality.]

@coffeemath I think you're right, and I amended my title and body of the question.

The proposition is true. Indeed, if all members of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are negative then it converges, which implies the required conclusion. Otherwise, replacing $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ by its subsequence, if needed, we can suppose that $a_1>0$. Pick $\varepsilon'>0$ such that $\varepsilon'\le\varepsilon/2$ and $\varepsilon'\le a_1$ and for each natural $n$ put $f(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{a_n}{\varepsilon'}\right\rfloor$.
If for some natural $n$ we have $f(n)=f(n+2)$ then pick $n_1=n$, $n_2=n+1$, and $n_3=n+2$.
Otherwise the series $\sum_{m\in f(\mathbb N)}^\infty \frac 1m$ diverges, so by the weaker claim there exist natural $n_1<n_2<n_3$ such that $(f(n_3)-f(n_2))-(f(n_2)-f(n_1))=0$.
Then
$$\left|\left(\frac{a_{n_3}}{\varepsilon'}-\frac{a_{n_2}}{\varepsilon'}\right)-
\left(\frac{a_{n_2}}{\varepsilon'}-\frac{a_{n_1}}{\varepsilon'}\right)\right|<2$$
and so
$$\left|(a_{n_3}-a_{n_2})-(a_{n_2}-a_{n_1})\right|<2\varepsilon'\le \varepsilon.$$

What is "the weaker claim"?

@AdamRubinson "The weaker claim that $A$ must contain infinitely many arithmetic progressions of length $3$".

OK, but that weaker theorem is about increasing reciprocal integer sequences, whereas my question is about increasing real sequences. So I don't see what $A$ is  in relation to your answer. Maybe I am not understanding your answer and it's my fault, but please be make your definition of $A$ more explicit.

@AdamRubinson Oops, sorry. Here $A$ is $f(\mathbb N)$. I corrected this.
